# Variable is jumping to a higher scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, memory, scope

I noticed a bug in my code a couple days ago and have no idea why it's happening. It seems a variable defined in a lower scope is somehow jumping up to a higher one. Anyone know what's happening here? Dumbed down code:

```
console.log(a) 

for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    var a = 5 

console.log(a)
```

The first console log always prints undefined
But the second console log always prints 5? 
Shouldn't variable a only exist in the for loop's scope and be cleared from memory once the for loop is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables defined with `var` are "function scoped", so they are accessible anywhere in the function. `let` and `const` however have "block scoping", they will behave like you expect:

```
{
  let a = 1;
  var b = 2;
}

console.log(a, b); // not defined, 2
```